# SQL Query to retrieve total order count for each user

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> Write an SQL command that retrieves last name and first name of all customers and the order numbers of orders they have placed…

CustDetails TABLE: http://prntscr.com/msicdp
OrderDetails TABLE: http://prntscr.com/msichp

I am trying to display list of all users from CustDetails (table), with an additional column, "TotalOrders", that counts how many orders each user have from OrderDetails (table) with COUNT(*), but it seems like I have no idea what am I doing.

I've tried LEFT JOIN paired with `COUNT(*) AS [Total Orders]` and I am getting all kind of errors whatever I try

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustDetails.*, OrderDetails.CustRef,COUNT(*) AS [Order_number]
FROM CustDetails
LEFT JOIN OrderDetails ON CustDetails.CustRef = OrderDetails.CustRef
GROUP BY CustDetails.FName
--SELECT CustDetails.CustRef, count(*) AS NUM
--  FROM CustDetails GROUP BY CustRef
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please quote/describe the results that make you doubt your competency. (Note that the task quoted does *not* ask for the *number of orders*, but for *`the order numbers`*.)

Comment: @greybeard oh i see... maybe they just want order_ref number for each user...
what if 1 user have more than 1 order... i am confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put `*` with `GROUP BY`. If you are using `GROUP BY`, all non-aggregated columns should be present in your `GROUP BY` clause.

You need to write your query like the following.

```
select c.CustRef,
       c.LName,
       c.Fname,
       sum(case when od.CustRef is null then 0 else 1 end) TotalOrders
from CustDetails c
left join OrderDetails od on od.CustRef =c.CustRef
group by c.CustRef ,c.LName, C.Fname
```

In case you need all the columns you can try like the following without `GROUP BY`.

```
select *,
       (select count(*) from OrderDetails od where  od.CustRef =c.CustRef) TotalOrders
from CustDetails c
```

Another way of doing it using `PARTITION BY`

```
select * from
(
select c.*,
        sum(case when od.CustRef is null then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by c.CustRef) as TotalOrders,
        row_number() over (partition by c.CustRef order by (select 1)) rn
from CustDetails c
left join OrderDetails od on od.CustRef =c.CustRef
) t
where rn=1
```

Comment: thank you that is all i needed... i have question 
why did you use coalesce() ? iv tried with out it and it works same... hmm ?
also why do we have to include all columns in group by ?

Thank you upfront @PSK

Comment: coalesce was initially used to change null to 0, but you don't need coalesce in your case.

Comment: @Bournee, I have updated the answer to include all columns